# Wildcards in Assertion on groovy-generated dates?

Tags: groovy, soapui

We are using SoapUI to test a Webservice of ours. This Webservice generates different Timestamps after a predictable pattern, so we use a groovy script to generate them on the SoapUI side and use these in assertions to assert the correct calculation on the webserver side. So far so good, it works like a charm on dates (pattern yyyy-MM-dd) and Timestamps with fixed hours / minutes (pattern yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm':00.000'). We use variations of this script to do this, sometimes adding days, months, hours and so forth:

```
def sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();       
instance.setTime(new Date());
Date date= instance.getTime();
s = sdf.format(date)
return s
```

===

Now I run into the following problem: This new project generates exact timestamps, down to the millisecond. Problem is, I cannot accuratly predict this, SoapUI generates the dates slightly earlier (thats no surprise, just a fact) than the webservice, and so there is a discrepancy of around 100 to 500 milliseconds between the timestamps.

I tried to add wildcards (*) (and enabled them, too) into this pattern to ignore the millisecond part, since it was deemed uneccessary as long as the second is right, but I guess they don't work within groovy scripts. Is there a way to make them work? Are there other approaches to check wether the timestamp down to the second is correct, and then ignore the milliseconds?

Comment: Dropping .SSS from the SimpleDateFormat would ignore the milliseconds. Did you try that? Remember you can still retain Z the time zone.

Comment: Well I cannot change the xml output, so the .sssZ is a given. What I tried is the format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss and then adding a wildcard to this, ie `${NameOfScript#NameOfCalculatedDate}*`, but in this case, the wildcard is treated as text.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy! In a Script Assertion find the difference between the date you get back and "now", and assert that the difference is less than some tolerance.

```
def nowDate = new Date()

def sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")
def currentDate = sdf.parse(context.expand('${getCurrentDateTime#ResponseAsXml#//*:current}'))

def minutesDiff = Math.abs(nowDate.getTime() - currentDate.getTime()) / 1000 / 60

assert minutesDiff < 5 : "Too great of a difference with server!"
```